# How can I use XPath to concatenate elements?

Tags: xml, xpath, rdf

I an analysing an XML document with XPath and I have the following data:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="https://<server>/ccm/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.WorkItem/57108">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://open-services.net/ns/cm#ChangeRequest"/>
    <dcterms:type rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Defect</dcterms:type>
    <dcterms:identifier rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">57108</dcterms:identifier>
    <dcterms:title rdf:parseType="Literal">
        The page does not scroll, Save Button not clickable
    </dcterms:title>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="https://<server>/ccm/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.WorkItem/56645">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://open-services.net/ns/cm#ChangeRequest"/>
    <dcterms:type rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Defect</dcterms:type>
    <dcterms:identifier rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">56645</dcterms:identifier>
    <dcterms:title rdf:parseType="Literal">
        NewMobApp Android: behavior of the swipe is incorrect
    </dcterms:title>
</rdf:Description>
```

What I am trying to do is format the data so that I get the following output:

```
57108 - The page does not scroll, Save Button not clickable
56645 - NewMobApp Android: behavior of the swipe is incorrect
```

Is this at all possible?  I have tried

```
String workItemNodes = (String) (xpath.evaluate(workItemMembersXPath, source, XPathConstants.STRING));
```

where

```
String workItemMembersXPath ="concat(//dcterms:identifier, //dcterms:title)";
```

but it only returns the first result.  I am trying to somehow put it into a NodeList, but I am not having much luck.  I am still new to XPath.

Am I on the right track, is this even possible, and are there better/easier ways of going about it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: it looks like your working with an RDF format, you might want to consider using [jena](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/rdf/index.html) instead of xpath. Actually I am not too familiar with rdf/jena. RDF can be expressed as XML so that would suppose that you can use XPath.

Using XPath I'd suggest using the `/text()` to get the text content of a node, this should help you overcome the empty lines in the `title` element (above and below the actual title).

```
String workItemMembersXPath ="concat(//dcterms:identifier/text(), //dcterms:title/text())";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not providing a direct answer, but I feel this is important information.

I urge you to not handle RDF/XML with XPath. We have tried that at work and it is a horrible, error-prone idea.

The main problem that you have is that the XML you will access is not static. And I don't only mean the number of statements, but the representation of these statements in RDF/XML. Whatever you use to serialize your graph in RDF/XML will, I am pretty sure of that, not guarantee you the same output each time. That right there should tell you to abandon the idea of using XPath.

For example, it's perfectly valid to express the graph like this:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="https://<server>/ccm/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.WorkItem/56645">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://open-services.net/ns/cm#ChangeRequest"/>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="https://<server>/ccm/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.WorkItem/56645">
    <dcterms:type rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Defect</dcterms:type>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="https://<server>/ccm/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.WorkItem/56645">
    <dcterms:identifier rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">56645</dcterms:identifier>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="https://<server>/ccm/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.WorkItem/56645">
    <dcterms:title rdf:parseType="Literal">
        NewMobApp Android: behavior of the swipe is incorrect
    </dcterms:title>
</rdf:Description>
```

That's the same subgraph as above, just represented slightly different. While one XPath expression might work with this, if you continue to exploit RDF using XPath you will run into problems with this sooner or later, I can promise you that.